# WHY ItemizeOverlay produce ArrayOutOfBoundException Not Always Occure This issue?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am showing POI's List on google map as:-

1- User Zoom-In or Zoom-Out a webservice call which responce xml of properties in perticular location.

2- After getting property we have to filter those properties which have same lat,long and show those number on bubbles on map(say 3 list have same lat ,long put that list into a arrayList and show on bubbles 3).

3- but when I seldom not always I am zooming map following Exception occurs:

```
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 length=0
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getIndexToDraw(ItemizedOverlay.java:211)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.draw(ItemizedOverlay.java:240)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9304)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2586)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
  06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9307)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:419)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2076)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1706)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1420)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2066)
 06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
06-27 15:10:57.269: E/AndroidRuntime(4968):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I am using This code:-`

```
    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

private class Mapdatatask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try 
        {
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();  
            URL sourceUrl=new URL(ListURL);
            System.out.println("----ListURL------"+ListURL);
            InputStream inputStream=sourceUrl.openStream();  
            //add if necessary the PushBack measure to safeguard the intended purpose here if really happening  
            //that you can actually ascertain it by saving a local copy for inspection  
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));  
            String line;  
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {  
                sb.append(line+"\n");  
            }  
            br.close(); 

            SAXParserFactory spff=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            spff.setNamespaceAware(true); 
            SAXParser spp=spff.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr=spp.getXMLReader();
            myHandler=new ApplicationHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sb.toString())));  
            //xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
            valueoftotal = ApplicationHandler.value;


        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {

            try 
            {
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();  
                URL sourceUrl=new URL(ListURL);
                InputStream inputStream=sourceUrl.openStream();  
                //add if necessary the PushBack measure to safeguard the intended purpose here if really happening  
                //that you can actually ascertain it by saving a local copy for inspection  
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));  
                String line;  
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {  
                    sb.append(line+"\n");  
                }  
                br.close(); 
                inputStream.close();
                SAXParserFactory spff=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                spff.setNamespaceAware(true); 
                SAXParser spp=spff.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr=spp.getXMLReader();
                Log.e("ListURL to parse ",""+ListURL);

                myHandler=new ApplicationHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);
                System.out.println(""+sb);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sb.toString())));  
                //xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
                valueoftotal = ApplicationHandler.value;
                //arrayList = myHandler.getParsedData();

            }
            catch(IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("parse exception0"," dont know why");
                Log.e("XML Error ",e.toString());

        return 1;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
    {
        if(valueoftotal!=null && !valueoftotal.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(valueoftotal) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(valueoftotal) <= 100)
            {
                OverlayItem oi=null;
                if(myHandler.getParsedData()!=null)
                {
                    ArrayList<Applicationdataset> arrayList = myHandler.getParsedData();
                    //mlist = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>();
                    myvectorlist = new Vector<ArrayList<Applicationdataset>>();
                    //mlist.addAll(arrayList);
                    System.out.println(arrayList.size()+"++++++++++");
                    Map<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> mlistVector = groupTheList(arrayList);
                    myvectorlist = putIntoVector(mlistVector);
                    for(int mindex=0;mindex<myvectorlist.size();mindex++)
                    {
                        if(myvectorlist.get(mindex)==null)
                        {
                            myvectorlist.remove(mindex);
                        }
                        if(myvectorlist.get(mindex).size()==0)
                        {
                            myvectorlist.remove(mindex);
                        }
                    }
                }
                linearbottom2.setClickable(true);
                synchronized (oi) {
                    mapOverlays.clear();
                    overlay.removeAll();
                }

                lineartabbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mapbar);

                if(myvectorlist != null && myvectorlist.size() > 1)
                {
                    Applicationdataset data = null;
                    for(int i = 0; i < myvectorlist.size(); i++)
                    { 
                        {
                            data = myvectorlist.get(i).get(0);
                            String latvalue = data.getLatitude().toString();
                            String lonvalue = data.getLongitude().toString();

                            GeoPoint point = null;
                            try
                            {
                                point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(latvalue)*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lonvalue)*1E6));
                            }
                            catch (NumberFormatException e) 
                            {
                            }

                            if(point != null)
                            {
                                oi = overlay.createItem(i);
                                if(overlay!=null)
                                {
                                  if(oi!=null)
                                  {
                                      System.out.println("overlay.size()--"+overlay.size());
                                    if(overlay.size()!=0) 
                                    {
                                        overlay.addItem(oi);

                                        if(myvectorlist.size() == 1)
                                        {
                                            mc.animateTo(point);
                                            mc.setCenter(point);
                                            mc.setZoom(16);
                                        }   
                                    }
                                  }

                                }//end
                            }

                    }

                    System.out.println("+++size of overlay++++"+overlay.size());

                    mapOverlays.add(overlay);

                    mapView.invalidate();
                }


                textViewpopup.setText(valueoftotal+" listings found.");
                linearlayoutpopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                RunAnimationslisting();

            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(valueoftotal) > 100)
            {

                Eyelidmessage(valueoftotal+" listings found. \n Zoom-in, press the locate button below or select the refine button above to display fewer properties. ");
                lineartabbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mapwithoutlist);
                linearbottom2.setClickable(false);                  

            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(valueoftotal) == 0)
            {
                GoneAnimations();
                lineartabbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mapwithoutlist);
                linearbottom2.setClickable(false);
                customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(activity);  
                customizeDialog.setTitle("Sorry");  
                customizeDialog.setMessage("No Listing Found");  
                customizeDialog.show();
            }
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        currenttask = null;
    }

}

private  class GoogleMapViewOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay 
{
    ImageButton bluebutton,savebutton,closebutton;

    ImageThreadLoader imageloader;

    //final MapController mc;
    TextView text1,text2,text3,text4,textup;
    ImageView imageview;

    private PopupPanel panel = new PopupPanel(R.layout.mappopup);
    private Drawable marker;
    private Context mContext;


    public GoogleMapViewOverlay(Drawable drawable, MapView mapView,
            Activity activity2)
    {
        //super(drawable);
        super(boundCenterBottom(drawable));
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();         

        items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        marker = drawable;
        mContext = mapView.getContext();
        mc = mapView.getController();
        this.activity = activity2;
        DB = new DatabaseHelper(activity2);
    }

    public void removeAll()
    {
        items.clear();
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }       

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) 
    {
        Projection getcoords;
        GeoPoint point = null;
        int size =0;
        String latvalue="";
        String lonvalue="";
        Point pcon = new Point(0,0);
        getcoords = mapView.getProjection();

        if(myvectorlist!=null)
        {
            if(myvectorlist.size()!=0)
            {
            size = myvectorlist.get(index).size();
            latvalue = myvectorlist.get(index).get(0).getLatitude().toString();
            lonvalue = myvectorlist.get(index).get(0).getLongitude().toString();    
            }
        }

        try
        {
            point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(latvalue)*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lonvalue)*1E6));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(getcoords!=null)
        {
            if(point!=null)
            {
                if(pcon!=null)
                {
                    getcoords.toPixels(point, pcon);        
                }                   
            }               
        }

        OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(point,"", "");
        if(size == 1)
         {
            boundCenterBottom(drawable);                
            oi.setMarker(drawable);
        }else
        if(size>1) 
        {
            Drawable d= writeOnDrawable(drawable1,size);
            boundCenterBottom(d);//drawable1                
            oi.setMarker(d);//drawable1 
        }


        return oi;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() 
    {
        //Log.e("","items.size()"+items.size());
        if (items != null && items.size() > 0)
            return items.size();
        else 
            return 0;       
    }

    public void addItem(OverlayItem item) 
    {
        System.out.println("adddoverlayitem "+items+"\titem"+item);
        try {

            items.add(item);
            setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
            populate();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

class PopupPanel
  {
    // View popup;
     PopupPanel(int layout)
       {
        ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)mapView.getParent();
        popup = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false);
        }
    View getView() {
        return(popup);
    }

    void show(boolean alignTop)
    {
        popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        if (alignTop) 
        {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);            

            lp.setMargins(65, 100, 0, 0);

        }
        else
        {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 60);
        }

        hide();

        ((ViewGroup)mapView.getParent()).addView(popup, lp);            

        isVisible=true;

    }

    void hide() {

        if (isVisible)
        {
            isVisible=false;
            ((ViewGroup)popup.getParent()).removeView(popup);
        }
    }
}

public void Eyelidmessage(String message)
{
    textViewpopup.setText(message);
    linearlayoutpopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);              
    RunAnimations();
}

private void RunAnimationslisting() {

    Animation a;
    a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    a.reset();

    linearlayoutpopup.clearAnimation();
    a.setFillAfter(true);
    linearlayoutpopup.startAnimation(a);

    a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("@@doneanimation listner works 1@@");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                GoneAnimationslisting();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

    });

}

private void GoneAnimationslisting() {

    Animation a1;
    a1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate1);
    a1.reset();

    linearlayoutpopup.clearAnimation();
    a1.setFillAfter(true);
    linearlayoutpopup.startAnimation(a1);


    a1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("@@doneanimation listner works 1@@");

            linearlayoutpopup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}

private Drawable writeOnDrawable(Drawable objdrawable, int size)
 {
    String text = ""+size;
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)objdrawable).getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    paint.setTypeface((Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD)));
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    float txtwidth = paint.measureText(text);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

   // canvas.drawText(text, 0, , paint);
    canvas.drawText(text,((bitmap.getWidth()/2)-(txtwidth/2)),bitmap.getHeight()/2, paint);

    Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
    return d;
}


private Map<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> groupTheList(ArrayList<Applicationdataset> arrayList) {
    Map<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> map = new HashMap<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>>();
    for (Applicationdataset appSet : arrayList) {
        Key key = new Key(appSet.getLatitude(), appSet.getLongitude());
        ArrayList<Applicationdataset> list = map.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(appSet);
    }
    return map;
}

public class Key {
    String _lat;
    String _lon;

    Key(String lat, String lon) {
        _lat = lat.trim();
        _lon = lon.trim();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        //if (this == o) return true;
       // if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        //Key key = (Key) o;

        //if (!_lat.equals(key._lat)) return false;
        //if (!_lon.equals(key._lon)) return false;
        return o instanceof Key
        && (_lat.equals(((Key)o)._lat))
        && (_lon.equals(((Key)o)._lon));


        //return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return _lat.hashCode() + _lon.hashCode();

    }
}

private Vector<ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> putIntoVector(Map<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> myMap)
 {
    Vector<ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> mvectorlist = new Vector<ArrayList<Applicationdataset>>();
    Iterator<Entry<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>>> miterator = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (miterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> pairs = (Map.Entry<Key, ArrayList<Applicationdataset>>)miterator.next();
        mvectorlist.add(pairs.getValue());
        miterator.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }

    return mvectorlist;

}
}
```

Anyone help me I unable to solve this issue till now near about 10 hours I have been spends plaese see this..

Comment: dont call condition like this way "if(myvectorlist!=null && myvectorlist.size()!=0)" instead of this try this "if(myvectorlist!=null){if(myvectorlist.size()!=0){}}"

Comment: @AndroidCoader: Sorry, but that's just wrong advice. There are quite a few things I'd raise in a code review about the above code, but there is nothing wrong with having two ANDed conditions inside the brackets. Also, please format code in your comments. If anything about that line should be changed, the second condition should be changed to `!list.isEmpty()` instead of `list.size() != 0` and a better name should be chosen for `mvectorlist`.

Comment: Sorry But this is not reason of exception please guide me needful thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 length=0` means that you are trying to access an element of an `ArrayList` when the size is zero.  Go back through your code and make sure you're not trying to access an empty list.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I think I know what you're problem is.  I think you're using `createItem` to try and add overlays to your `ItemizedOverlay`.  This function is poorly named, and does not actually create an item.  It simply returns an item from your array of `OverlayItems`.  You need to use `GoogleMapViewOverlay.addOverlay(OverlayItem)` to truly add an `OverlayItem` to the map.  Try creating a couple test Overlays with random coordinates and see if that works out.  Remember to stop using `createItem()` and start using `addItem()`.  If this isn't your problem then post all of of your code and maybe we can help you out a little better.

Comment: The stack trace shows that behind the scenes your trying to draw an item whose index doesn't exist.

Comment: In fact, I've received the same error, usually from trying to draw an `Overlay` object that was either not correctly instantiated, or `null`.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your `ArrayList` of overlays, and not your `myvectorlist`.  Basically, make sure you're adding items to your `ItemizedOverlay`.  Then your array of overlays will have a size greater than zero, so you can access the index's.

Comment: I guess, how are you attempting to add items to your overlay?

Comment: Please improve in my code because last 3 hours I am struggling but except frustration nothing to get please help..

Comment: I have been added sniipet of whole code which contains part related to this please help me...

Comment: You need to add your `ItemizedOverlay` to the map by using `mapView.getOverlays().add(oi)`

Comment: I have been use this but this is not reason of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at what point in your code the error is arising, but you could try changing:

```
if (size == 1) {
} else {
}
```

to:

```
if (size == 1) {
} else if (size > 1) {
}
```

That might get rid of your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

After spend more time I have reach that My problem due to this post:-
[Async Task throw ConCurrent Modification Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11257003/1417177)